# Ansible update variables value in a playbook and use them in another

Tags: variables, ansible, roles, inventory

I'm a new user of ansible, and I'm not sure to have correctly understood the way variables actually works.

I'm working on an ansible project to manage my pfSense firewall. 
I have defined some roles to execute specific actions on them, and I'm having problems with the roles "**pfbackup**" & "**pfrestore**":

- My role backup *download the config.xml* file on each node and rename it using the ansible_hostname and the current date.
- I would like to store the **name of this config file** for **each
  node** in a ***variable*** which can be read by my other playbook
  that is using my role "pfrestore", and this role will be used to upload and restore the last
  registered config file to the firewall and reload the server.

So, in my first playbook I have defined a value for **hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf** and I'm able to print it during the playbook execution.

```
- name: Setup config file variable for each node

  set_fact:

    conf: /roles/pfbackup/files/{{ item }}.xml

    cacheable: true

  loop:

  - "{{ output.stdout }}"



- name: Display defined variable for all hosts

  debug:

    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf
```

**Extract of the execution of my pfbackup playbook:**

```
TASK [pfbackup : Setup config file variable for each node] ****************************************************************************************************************

ok: [fwlab00] => (item=FWLAB00.local.test_19-05-2020_09-45)

ok: [fwlab01] => (item=FWLAB01.local.test_19-05-2020_09-45)

ok: [fwlab02] => (item=FWLAB02.local.test_19-05-2020_09-45)



TASK [pfbackup : Display defined variable for all hosts] ******************************************************************************************************************

ok: [fwlab00] => {

    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf": "/roles/pfbackup/files/FWLAB00.local.test_19-05-2020_09-45.xml"

}

ok: [fwlab01] => {

    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf": "/roles/pfbackup/files/FWLAB01.local.test_19-05-2020_09-45.xml"

}

ok: [fwlab02] => {

    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf": "/roles/pfbackup/files/FWLAB02.local.test_19-05-2020_09-45.xml"

}
```

**BUT** once my 1st playbook execution is over, it seems that **the variable disappear** and is not displayed when I print hostvars in my other playbook or with the debug module:

```
(ansible2.7.10) [svc-ansible@labo-dynfi-00 pfsense-ansible]$ ansible -i hosts_init all -m debug -a var=hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf

    fwlab00 | SUCCESS => {

        "hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

    }

    fwlab02 | SUCCESS => {

        "hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

    }

    fwlab01 | SUCCESS => {

        "hostvars[inventory_hostname].conf": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

    }
```

How can I write my variable correctly to make it accessible by my other playbooks?

**EDIT:**

I have created a global playbook to define my roles.
If I launch the playbook it does the trick because both roles are in the same playbook.

**BUT this is not a solution** because to restore the lastest conf file, I need to launch the backup role before the restore role... making it pointless.

```
- hosts: "pfsense"
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: pfbackup
      vars:
        test: file.xml
  tags:
    - backup

- hosts: "pfsense"
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: pfrestore
      vars:
        test_bis: filebis.xml
        net:
          bordeaux:
            conf_save: config-FWLAB00.xml
          toulouse:
            conf_save: config-FWLAB01.xml
          rognac:
            conf_save: config-FWLAB02.xml
  tags:
    - restore
```

I wonder if it's possible to export my 3 values (depending on the number of host of course) in vars files during the backup role execution making them statics, and then in my restore role, import all the vars files. So I will only need to launch my backup once to setup my variables and be able to restore a previous configuration on every firewall.
But I have no idea on how to make it work!

Comment: hey. you want to set a variable (conf) in one role (i.e.pfbackup) and use the same variable(conf) in another role(pfrestore)? and this both role are called from different playbooks or the same?

Comment: Hello each role is called by a specific playbook, but I know i can put all my roles in a "global playbook" and setup tags for each role and use them by calling my ansible-playbook with the option "-t <tag>"

Comment: i would say you should create one master playbook and create two different play. first role can be called in first play and second role can be called in second play. but both the play must include in one master playbook. Then you should run the master playbook. You will be able to access then. I have tried this way and it works.

Comment: @shreyash I tried your way, see my "edit"